# Wacom Tablet settings missing

Tags: multiple-monitors, wacom, graphics-tablet

I am running Ubuntu Studio 14.04 with tree monitors on an NVidia video card. I have a large Wacom tablet connected. The tablet is seen and works. Two of the monitors are the connected DVI and are the same models, the third one is connected via HDMI. I am having two problems:

1) The tablet app in the system settings keeps disappearing from system settings.

2) When it is there, I try to map the tablet to monitor number 2 and no matter which of the DVI monitors I select, it always maps to the first one. When I select the third monitor it will map to that monitor (as expected).

How do I get the tablet app / settings to stay in the system settings.
How to I map the tablet to the second monitor?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems a bug; you can check the command line trick in http://askubuntu.com/a/548019/16395 to see if it helps --- but it probably needs to be reported at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page